# Laravel 5 (URL not showing search parameters)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

New to Laravel,

My form looks like this

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => array('SearchController@postReviews' ), 'class'=>'form-inline')) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon" style="width:110px;">Location</div>
            <input type="text" 
                   class="form-control "  
                   id="mapsearch" name="mapsearch" 
                   placeholder="Enter City,Pin or Address" 
                   style="height:43px; min-width:402px; font-size:1.0em;" required/>
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                {!! Form::select('size', 
                    array('Car' => 'Car', '2-Wheeler' => '2-Wheeler'), 
                    'Car', 
                    ['id'=> 'carmodel', 'class' => 'form-control input-sm', 'style'=>'width:200px;',
                    'required']) 
                !!}
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control input-sm" name="input_lat" id="input_lat" required>
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control input-sm" name="input_lng" id="input_lng" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn_search" style="width:200px;height:42px;">Search</button>
   </div>

 </form>
```

And my controller looks like

```
public function postReviews()
{
    $location = Input::get('mapsearch');
    $input_lat = Input::get('input_lat');
    $input_lng = Input::get('input_lng');


    $inputs = ($input_lat  && $input_lng);
    if (!$inputs) {

      $input_lat = 22.5667;
      $input_lng = 88.3667;
    }...
```

Now everything is working fine. I am able to generate results with no issues.

What is troubling me is when I hit search my URL remains the same.

I.e. Before search URL is `http://localhost/reviews`
     After search URL is `http://localhost/reviews`
what should I change so that my url after search button click shows

`http://localhost/reviews/(value from mapsearch field)`

Answer (score 0):

When you use a POST request, the Input values are sent over post and aren't appended to the URL (as opposed to a get request where they would be sent to something like localhost/reviews?mapsearch=xxxx&input_lat=xxxxx&input_lng=xxxxx).  In order to add that segment to the URL you would have to do one of two things:

1) in the Controller, handle the inputs and then redirect them to a route mapped to /reviews/{mapsearch}

or

2) use a bit of javascript on the page to update the URL to show the mapsearch parameter.  In order to update the URL they see without sending them to a new page you'd need to use history.pushState.  So in your view you would have

```
<script>
history.pushState({},"URL Rewrite Example","http://localhost/reviews/{{Input::get('mapsearch')}}")
</script>
```

This would update their URL to show that parameter.  This is not supported by all browsers, notably IE <10

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I tried the first method but looks like I missed the point. I did this    return view('/reviewresults/{location}',compact('results','address_markes','car_oems','bike_oems','location','car_types','bike_types')); but it gave me View [.reviewresults.{location}] not found error. Can you please elaborate your first answer.

Comment: You will need to register the route for `/reviewresults/{location}` in your routes file, and map it to your view.  Then you could use `return redirect("/reviewresults/$location",compact('results','address_markes','car_oems','‌​bike_oems','location','car_types','bike_types'));`

Answer (score 0):

First create a controller action

```
public function reviewWithUri($uri,$data){
    return view('YOUR_VIEW_FILE')->with(['data'->$data]);
}
```

Then change your postReview returns to redirect to this action.

```
public function postReview(){
    ........
    return redirect()->action('ReviewController@reviewWithUri', ['uri' =>$uri,'data'=>$data]);
}
```

Finally routing

```
Route::get('review/{uri}', ['uses' => 'ReviewController@reviewWithUri', 'as' => 'review.uri']);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. When I pass my results to the view using with data, I get a response that URI is too big. and also I am seeing the sql results in the url which I don't want. Please suggest.

Comment: Oh, It should be `['uri' => $uri,'data' => $data]` in the second section.